# The text goes under the floated element

Tags: list, css-float

Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB7Wg.jpg
Here jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2fVbs/1/
How can I do that? :/

> li.help {display: block; margin-left: 15px;}
>   ul {list-style-type:none;list-style-position:inside;padding:0;margin:0;}
>   .avatar {float:left;width:100px;height:100px;background: url('http://') no-repeat;background-color:#000;}

```
<div class="avatar"></div>
<ul>
<li class="help">One</li>
<ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Give your `<ul>` a `width`. and `float:left;` And you need to close the last `<ul>` tagg

```
ul {
   ...
   width:300px; 
   float:left;
}
```

Updated [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2fVbs/5/)

More like the image example, **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/2fVbs/7/)**

**Better solution.**

**Html:**

```
<div id="post">
    <img src="" />
    <p> text......</p>
</div>
```

**Css:**

```
#post { width: 600px;}
#post img {float:left; width: 100px; margin: 0 10px 0 0;}
#post p {float:left; width: 490px;}
```

Comment: I can't flaot the ul because every post of the site goes between <li></li> and near every post there should be the avatar of the person that has posted!

edit: Sorry If I didn't specified it at the beginning..!

Comment: And how do you want to get all the posts in differecnt <li> with avatars, if you are putting the avatar outside the <ul> thats not possible...

Comment: Maybe I should put the <div class="avatar"></div> inside the <li></li> in order to make it rendered in each post!

Comment: Check my update, it is better to do it like that, inside a `foreach` (php) its much cleaner that a `list`